# freopen and cout creating internal error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cout, freopen, c1001

I'm trying to read and write some files, but i get "ERROR C1001, internal error happened in compiler" every time i try to `std::cout` something to my `output.out` file.

Why ?

(i used `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` in preprocesssor definition to be able to use `freopen()`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <deque>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

freopen("C:\\somepath\\input.in", "r", stdin);
freopen("C:\\somepath\\output.out", "w", stdout);

int t;
std::cin >> t;
std::cout << t << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    std::vector <int> x, h;
    x.resize(n);
    h.resize(n);
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        std::cin >> x[j] >> h[j];
        std::cout<< x[j] << h[j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

EDIT : as Nighteen said, i had some errors in my code (n++, no vector resizing, now corrected)
But the bug, still there in some way : 
The code is compiling in this state, but as soon as i try put cout a string, the same probleme appears 
like adding `<<" "` in my `std::cout<< x[j] << h[j] << std::endl;`

```
in the std::cout<< x[j] <<" "<< h[j] << std::endl;
```

Comment: Put your code into a `main` function.

Comment: i got a main fonction, i just didn't paste it

Comment: Could you give us an example input.in and the corresponding output.out you want?

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/problems/DEFOREST  there is the input/output example in that page ^^

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles fine in MSVC 15.5.2 assuming you put the code in a main block. Proof [here](https://prnt.sc/i14yj4).

Even though the compilation is OK, the code seems not to work out as it should. First of all, you can't `std::cin >> x[j] >> h[j];`. Create a temporary variable to store the input and then push it back into the vector:

```
int input1, input2;
std::cin >> input1 >> input2;

x.push_back(input1);
h.push_back(input2);
```

You should also note that this loop `for (int j = 0; j < n; n++)` never ends. The variable `j` should be increasing, not `n`. Whatever you are trying to achieve, this does not seem to be the way.

Comment: thanks, but the bug still there when i try to `cout` any string ! (look at edit)

Answer (score 0):

std::cout is a std::ostream used for outputting to the console. For outputting to files, used the classes std::ifstream and std::ofstream. Use the following syntax:

```
std::ifstream [ifstream_name](constructor parameters);
[ifstream_name] >> [container to store file contents];

std::ofstream [ofstream name](constructor parameters);
[ofstream_name] << [contents to write to file];
```

Comment: i'm trying to post on codechef, and `if` and `ofstream` aren't available, i just have `freopen`.